# Blank Page After Publishing ASP.NET Core v3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have just published an ASP.NET Core v3.1 app to a remote host, but it return a blank page (hosting server supports ASP.NET Core 3.1), how can I rectify that?

PS: I have not enable SSL, tried changing hostingmodel to "outprocess" in `web.config` but no success.

I used Visual Studio publishing tool with default configuration,

- Deployment mode: tried both Framework-dependant and self-contained
- Target runtime: tried both *portable* and *x86*

`Startup.cs`:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
            
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

`web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\app.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You need to enable Kestrel logging and then dig into both the Windows application event log and Kestrel log file. That can get you started.

Comment: It might be related to your configuration settings. Take a look at your `appsettings.json` file. check database connection string.

Comment: Are there any updates on this issue?

Comment: it is fixed now, i had to copy the View folder separately to the hosting location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed, i had to copy the View folder separately to the hosting location